# Why can't i use domain in selection filed?

Tags: field, selection, openerp-7

**I want to create my selection to sort only 'A' in listbox**

This is my code

```
class account_voucher(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.voucher'
    _columns = {
                'amount': fieSome one plz help me and thank you for you time to rend my word (sorry about my language :'|)lds.float('Fees', digit=(12,2)),
                'amount_mode': fields.selection([('a', 'A'),('b', 'B')], 'Amount Mode', select=True, change_default=True, track_visibility='always'),  
                }
```

and This is my xml view

```
<field name="amount_mode" style="width:11em" domain="[('amount_mode'), '=', 'a']"/>
```

Am i use the wrong systax or what?

*Some one plz help me and thank you for you time to rend my word (sorry about my language :'|)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

Structure of Domain is =>

```
domain=[('field_value','operator','value')]
```

correct is:-

```
<field name="amount_mode" 
       style="width:11em" 
       domain="[('amount_mode', '=', 'a')]"
```

You can also add domain in `.py file field` also.

And if you want to see that value is selection box default than you can add in `.py file`

for example.

```
_defaults = {
    'amount_mode': 'a',
}
```

Comment: i already use <field name="amount_mode" 
       style="width:11em" 
       domain="[('amount_mode', '=', 'a')]" with the right systex but it's dose't work again. It's becuase of selection?

Comment: but when i change my field to many2one and use domain it's work. what happen ?

Comment: yes, even I don't try yet, It's work with many2one field. In Selection field have issue. Generally, domain use for the restrict the value of field. In many2one, we have list of ids so we can easily restrict the value. Hope you understand. I advice to use many2one filed.